# .Net core 5 set default startup route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm an old school ASP.Net & AngularJS dev and I'm now working on an existing .Net 5 Core app (that will be migrated to .Net Core 6). This is new tech to me and I'm still figuring things out. One thing I expected to be very simple was to change the starting point of the web UI but I have not been able to make this work as expected.
Right now the app starts up on the default Controller Route, Home. I want to change this so instead of landing on Home (via myapp.mydomain.com) I want it to land on another controller, Clients (via myapp.mydomain.com/Clients).
I've tried making a change in Startup.cs where the default route is defined:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            //pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            pattern: "{controller=Clients}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

ClientsController:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ClientsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ClientsController> _logger;
        private readonly IClientService _service;
        private readonly IAppVersionService _appVersionService;
        private readonly IIisService _iisService;
        private readonly IWindowsServices _windowsServices;
        private readonly IAuthHelpers _authHelpers;

        public ClientsController(ILogger<ClientsController> logger, IClientService service, 
            IAppVersionService appVersionService, IIisService iisService, IWindowsServices windowsServices, IAuthHelpers authHelpers)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _service = service;
            _appVersionService = appVersionService;
            _iisService = iisService;
            _windowsServices = windowsServices;
            _authHelpers = authHelpers;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/Clients")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? pageNumber)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Client Index starting...");
            await SyncAppVersionsWithS3();
            await AddVersionsToViewData();
            ViewBag.Error = TempData["Error"];
            ViewBag.Success = TempData["Success"];
            var paginatedClients = await PaginatedList<ClientDto>
                .CreateAsync(_service.Query(), pageNumber ?? 1, 10);
            return View(paginatedClients);
        }
```

But that results in a 404 at startup. Back in the old asp.net days I'd just rt-click on a aspx file and select Set As Startup. I just want to do the equivalent here without it being a kludge. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: ,NET (Core) 5 is already out of support. It was a single-year "current" version that reached End-of-Life in May 2022. The current Long-Term-Release is .NET 6 and will be supported until 2024

Comment: Yeah we are working on moving to .Net Core 6 but this is an existing application. I think this stuff is pretty much the same across versions 5 & 6 too.

Comment: Can you show ClientsController?

Comment: @clhereistian Adding how it starts to the post, LMK if there is another part you need to see.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `[Route]` attribute in default controller (Clients). if you are defined `[Route("Clients")]`, only access with domain/clients.

solution 1: Remove route attribute as `Clients, Clients/Index, ""` are handled automatically (MapRoute in program.cs)

```
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? pageNumber)
 {
     ...
 }
```

solution 2 multiple route: (in this case there is no need to change the default route)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
[Route("Clients")]
[Route("Clients/Index/{pageNumber?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? pageNumber)
{
         ...
}
```

Comment: This is correct. Remove the routing attribute. From the .Core routing documentation:

"It's typical to use conventional routes for controllers serving HTML pages for browsers, and attribute routing for controllers serving REST APIs."